# Duplicating parent, child and grandchild records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-insert

I have a parent table that represents a document of-sorts, with each record in the table having *n* children records in a child table. Each child record can have *n* grandchild records. These records are in a *published* state. When the user wants to modify a published document, we need to clone the parent and all of its children and grandchildren.

The table structure looks like this:

#### Parent

```
CREATE TABLE [ql].[Quantlist] (
    [QuantlistId]   INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [StateId]       INT           NOT NULL,
    [Title]         VARCHAR (500) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Quantlist] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([QuantlistId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Quantlist_State] FOREIGN KEY ([StateId]) REFERENCES [ql].[State] ([StateId])
);
```

#### Child

```
CREATE TABLE [ql].[QuantlistAttribute]
(
    [QuantlistAttributeId] INT IDENTITY (1, 1),
    [QuantlistId] INT NOT NULL,
    [Narrative] VARCHAR (500) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_QuantlistAttribute] PRIMARY KEY ([QuantlistAttributeId]), 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_QuantlistAttribute_QuantlistId] FOREIGN KEY ([QuantlistId]) REFERENCES [ql].[Quantlist]([QuantlistId]),
)
```

#### Grandchild

```
CREATE TABLE [ql].[AttributeReference]
(
    [AttributeReferenceId] INT IDENTITY (1, 1),
    [QuantlistAttributeId] INT NOT NULL,
    [Reference] VARCHAR (250) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_QuantlistReference] PRIMARY KEY ([AttributeReferenceId]), 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_QuantlistReference_QuantlistAttribute] FOREIGN KEY ([QuantlistAttributeId]) REFERENCES [ql].[QuantlistAttribute]([QuantlistAttributeId]),
)
```

In my stored procedure, i pass in the `QuantlistId` I want to clone as `@QuantlistId`. Since the `QuantlistAttribute` table has a `ForeignKey` I can easily clone that as well.

```
INSERT INTO [ql].[Quantlist] (
    [StateId],
    [Title],
) SELECT 
    1,
    Title,
    FROM [ql].[Quantlist]
    WHERE QuantlistId = @QuantlistId

SET @ClonedId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

INSERT INTO ql.QuantlistAttribute(
        QuantlistId
        ,Narrative)
    SELECT 
        @ClonedId,
        Narrative,
    FROM ql.QuantlistAttribute
    WHERE QuantlistId = @QuantlistId
```

The trouble comes down to the `AttributeReference`. If I cloned 30 `QuantlistAttribute` records, how do I clone the records in the reference table and match them up with the new records I just inserted in to the `QuantlistAttribute` table?

```
    INSERT INTO ql.AttributeReference(
            QuantlistAttributeId,
            Reference,)
        SELECT 
            QuantlistAttributeId,
            Reference,
        FROM ql.QuantlistReference
        WHERE ??? I don't have a key to go off of for this.
```

I thought I could do this with some temporary linking tables that holds the old attribute id's along with the new attribute id's. I don't know how to go about inserting the old Attribute Id's in to a temp table along with their new ones. Inserting the existing Attributes, by QuantlistId, is easy enough, but I can't figure out how to make sure I link the correct new and old Id's together in some way, so that the `AttributeReference` table can be cloned right. If I could get the `QuantlistAttribute` new and old Id's linked, I could join on that temp table and figure out how to restore the relationship of the newly cloned references, to the newly cloned attributes.

Any help on this would be awesome. I've spent the last day and a half trying to figure this out with no luck :/

Please excuse some of the SQL inconsistencies. I re-wrote up the sql real quick, trimming out a lot of additional columns, related-tables and constraints that weren't needed for this question.

#### Edit

After doing a little digging around, I found that OUTPUT might be useful for this. Is there a way to use OUTPUT to map the `QuantlistAttributeId` records I just inserted, to the `QuantlistAttributeId` they originated from?

Comment: Do you have any logical key in table `QuantlistAttribute` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `OUTPUT` to get the inserted rows.

1. You can insert the data into `QuantlistAttribute` based on the order of `ORDER BY c.QuantlistAttributeId ASC`
2. Have a temp table/table variable which 3 columns

   - an id identity column
   - new QuantlistAttributeId
   - old QuantlistAttributeId.
3. Use `OUTPUT` to insert new identity values of QuantlistAttribute into a temp table/table variable. 
   The new IDs are generated in the same order as `c.QuantlistAttributeId`
4. Use a `row_number()` ordered by `QuantlistAttributeId` to match the old `QuantlistAttributeId` and new `QuantlistAttributeIds` based on `row_number()` and `id` of the table variable and update the values or old QuantlistAttributeId in the table variable
5. Use the temp table and `join` with `AttributeReference` and insert records in one go.

***Note:*** 
`ORDER BY` during `INSERT INTO SELECT` and `ROW_NUMBER()` to get matching old  `QuantlistAttributeId` is required because looking at your question, there seems to be no other logical key to map old and new records together.

**Query for above Steps**

```
DECLARE @ClonedId INT,@QuantlistId INT = 0

INSERT INTO [ql].[Quantlist] (
    [StateId],
    [Title]
) SELECT 
    1,
    Title
    FROM [ql].[Quantlist]
    WHERE QuantlistId = @QuantlistId

SET @ClonedId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
--Define a table variable to store the new QuantlistAttributeID and use it to map with the Old QuantlistAttributeID
DECLARE @temp TABLE(id int identity(1,1), newAttrID INT,oldAttrID INT)

INSERT INTO ql.QuantlistAttribute(
        QuantlistId
        ,Narrative)
        --New QuantlistAttributeId are created in the same order as old QuantlistAttributeId  because of ORDER BY
        OUTPUT inserted.QuantlistAttributeId,NULL INTO @temp
    SELECT 
        @ClonedId,
        Narrative
    FROM ql.QuantlistAttribute c
    WHERE QuantlistId = @QuantlistId
    --This is required to keep new ids generated in the same order as old
    ORDER BY c.QuantlistAttributeId ASC

    ;WITH CTE AS
    (
        SELECT c.QuantlistAttributeId,
        --Use ROW_NUMBER to get matching id which is same as the one generated in @temp
        ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY c.QuantlistAttributeId ASC) id
        FROM ql.QuantlistAttribute c
        WHERE QuantlistId = @QuantlistId
    )
    --Update the old value in @temp 
    UPDATE T
    SET oldAttrID = CTE.QuantlistAttributeId
    FROM @temp T
    INNER JOIN CTE ON T.id = CTE.id


INSERT INTO ql.AttributeReference(
            QuantlistAttributeId,
            Reference)
        SELECT 
            T.NewAttrID,
            Reference
        FROM ql.AttributeReference R
        --Use OldAttrID to join with ql.AttributeReference and insert NewAttrID
        INNER JOIN @temp T
        ON T.oldAttrID = R.QuantlistAttributeId
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thanks a lot for the help. I had tried looking at table expressions, but had a hard time wrapping my head around them. I'm a C# dev, but don't write much SQL